# how do I make my jquery animation set to opacity 0 as it comes back down?

Tags: jquery

As the item goes up, it fades out.  Then the item will come back down again and start over.
I want to create a more continuous effect where the object is still invisible as its coming down after going up the first time, AND then fadesIn(), AND then start over.  Is that possible? Is there a better way to write this?

```
$(".item")
    .animate({"marginTop":"-100px",opacity:0}, 3000,'linear')
    .animate({"marginTop":"0px",opacity: 0.5}, 600, 'linear', runMyFunctionAgain);
```

Comment: Google suggests that when multiple animations are occurring a single timer is used. This would require some refactoring.

Comment: This can be achieved pretty easily using recursion and callbacks. OP, if you post markup along with your js, someone will step up and refactor it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually doesn't have concurrent timers so your approach works enough. Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edhwJ/) for an example of what I thought you wanted. In case there is an issue with the site, here is the code:

`<html>`

```
<div class="item">Some Item Content</div>​
```

`js`

```
var initAnime = (function StartAnimation(){
 $('.item').animate(
  {"marginTop":"-100px",opacity:0},
  3000,
  'linear',
  function(){
   $('.item').animate(
    {"marginTop":"0px"},
    600,
    'linear',
    function(){
     $('.item').animate(
      {opacity: 0.5}, 
      600, 
      'linear', 
      StartAnimation
     );
    }
   );
  }
 );
})();​
```

I added the extra indentation to make it clear what was where since it got a little chainish. Hope it makes it a little more readable.

Comment: Thanks Travis.  It's my first time working with Animate and this appears as close to what I am shooting for.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle to see if this is what you had in mind:

http://jsfiddle.net/BvQDs/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div id="clickMe">
    <a href="#">Click Me!</a>
</div>​
```

JavaScript:

```
var animate = function(){
    $(".item").animate({"marginTop":"-100px",opacity:0}, 1000,'linear', function(){
        $(this).hide()
               .css({'marginTop':'0px', opacity:100})
               .fadeIn(1000, animate());
    });
};

$('#clickMe').on('click', function(){
    animate();
});
```